# how to change tomcat from generating daily catalina logs as root user/group

Tags: java, tomcat, ubuntu

I would like to change the logs generated by tomcat as another user/group. Currently it is generating as root user and group. where can i make this configuration?

example

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root    16056 Sep 15 09:06 catalina.2015-09-15.log
```

would like it to be

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat   tomcat    16056 Sep 15 09:06 catalina.2015-09-15.log
```

Comment: Are you launching tomcat on your own or ar you using a packaged from debian ubuntu?

Comment: launching it on my own.